# Ebean Select only particular Column

Tags: playframework, ebean

i have a class product with fields id , name , price etc,...

i want to fetch only name from the table ..

Am currently using this query

```
 String sql =   "select name from product where price = 100";
 SqlQuery sqlQuery = Ebean.createSqlQuery(sql);
  List<SqlRow> list = sqlQuery.findList();
```

what is the alerternate way to find using  List but fetch only name

```
List<product> list = product.find.where("price = 100").select("name").findList();
```

i dont think the following query is efficient since it fetches all data and returns wat we filter it

```
  List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(product p: product.find.select("name").findList())
     {
        list.add(p.name);
    }


return list;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default `.select("name")` automatically includes the Id column. So in SQL you will see `select t0.id, t0.name from ...`

If you add `setDistinct(true)` to the query, then that tells Ebean to not include the Id column and you will see in SQL `select distinct t0.name from ...`

Try

`product.find
  .where().eq("price", 100)
  .setDistinct(true).select("name")
  .findList();`

Comment: Thanks for the Response .. But It returns all columns

Comment: What version of Ebean are you using?

Comment: it must be 3.3.4 since i am using play framework 2.3.x

Comment: That will be the problem (you probably know Ebean is at 7.x now and you're on a pretty old version there). Assuming you can't upgrade you could just use SqlQuery instead.

Answer (score 7):

Ebean has `findSingleAttributeList()` and `findSingleAtrribute()` so the alternative answer would be:

```
List<String> productNames =
  product.find
    .where().eq("price", 100)
    .select("name")
    .findSingleAttributeList();
```